# Node.js/Javascript: Failing mocha test with timeout on testing parsing XML to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

Can someone please help me figure out why am I failing the mocha test even after setting the timeout to 15000ms. I know it can be a memory leak etc but I cannot find it anywhere in my code. I used the chrome debugger and checked that the JS Heap uses 48MB memory at the max. (which is not too bad?) Here's the function I'm testing, it's in a file called `xmlParser.js`

```
var fs = require('fs'),
xml2js = require('xml2js'),
parser = new xml2js.Parser();

/**
 * [parse - parses a xml file to json]
 * @param  {[string]}   filename [name of the file to parse]
 * @param  {Function} callback [callback function]
 * @return {[Function]}            [returning callback function]
 */
function parse(filename, callback){
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log('cannot read file.');
            return callback(err);
        } else {
            parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){
                if(err) {
                   console.log('cannot parse file.');
                   return callback(err);
                }
                else {
                    return callback(null, result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

module.exports = {
    parse
}
```

What does it do? Parses a xml file to JSON. As simple as that! 
Here's how I'm testing it,

```
var assert = require('chai').assert,
    mocha = require('mocha'),
    xmlParser = require('../utils/xmlParser.js'),
    extractInformation = require('../utils/extractInformation.js');

//data-structures for parsed XML data (lists)
var logJSON = [], listJSON = [];

describe('parse xml files', function(){
    this.timeout(150000);
    it('should parse correctly', function(done){
        this.timeout(150000);
        setTimeout(done, 150000);
        xmlParser.parse(__dirname + "/../xml/svn_log_test.xml", function(err,  log) {
            if(err) {
                return done(err);
                // assert.equal(true, false);
            }
            this.logJSON = log["log"]["logentry"];
            xmlParser.parse(__dirname + "/../xml/svn_list_test.xml", function(err, list) {
                if(err) {
                    return done(err);
                    // assert.equal(true, false);
                }
                this.listJSON = list["lists"]["list"][0]["entry"];
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Now, before you say that I'm not using any assert statements as of now, yes I'm not. But it should pass anyway, right? It's not passing, it gets a timeout error after 15000s

Comment: Any reason why you're not calling done after setting `this.listJSON`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to decrease the setTimout to 14 seconds?

```
setTimeout(function () {
    done()
}, 140000);
```

The timers are not quite precise in javascript

Comment: Thank you! This along with adding done() after my `this.listJSON` (as said by @robertklep) solved it for me.